# box api v2: scope option "manage an enterprise"

Tags: box-api

What exactly is possible using the "manage an enterprise" scope in an application?

I have a client asking if it's possible for an app to access the event feed (and the corresponding files) for an ENTIRE account without a single user needing to have access to every file in the account. Would enabling the "manage an enterprise" scope grant an app this kind of access/functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is our fault for not providing enough detail. 'Manage an Enterprise' provides access to all of the methods available under the [users](http://developers.box.com/docs/#users) endpoint as well as [admin_logs](http://developers.box.com/docs/#events-get-events-in-an-enterprise).

Note that while this scope enables access to these capabilities, only certain user types (i.e. admin, coadmin) have these capabilities.

Comment: Okay, so just to clarify: with Manage an Enterprise enabled, an app can see everything that happens across the entire account in the event stream BUT it cannot actually access files across the entire account unless the account being used with the app already has access to those files?